# How to open JFrame from a class in different package?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, package

I'm working on a java Project and I've to open an jFrame from a jframe in different package. I've imported the files but on execution I'm getting null pointer exception.
n yes I'm creating project in netBeans so is there any method to make jframe public or any other method thru which I can access Jframe from different package?

Comment: Spend some time in understanding the code that is auto-generated. netBeans is a good tool but you need to learn at least some basis of Java as well as Swing application.

Comment: Please can you post your code, and the stack trace of the exception so that we can see what is going on?

Comment: @Braj i'm not able to find any option for changing specifier of jframe

Comment: Please see how to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You are likely to get better help if you post one for us to test.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the required frames belong to the same project? If not, copy the frame u want to your current project to whichever package in it.

Then in the current frame do the following:

FrameOfOtherPackage f = new FrameOfOtherPackage();
f.setVisible(true);